# Change picture when button is clicked JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying write code that will display a new picture (from a beach pic to a lake pic) when a button is clicked. Currently it is somewhat working but both pictures are showing up on the first click and the beach pic disappears on the second click.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Beach Photo </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Photo of Beach </h1>
    <h4>Click button below to see a photo of a beach</h4>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="show">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-margin">Show</button>
        <br>

      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="img">

      </div>

      <div class="image1">
        <img src="img/beach-pic.jpg" alt="photo of beach" id="img1">
        <img src="img/lake-pic.jpg" alt="photo of lake" id="img2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#show").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#img1").toggle();
    $("#img2").show();
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#img1 {
  display: none;
}

#img2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing or hiding the second image simply check whether the first image is shown or not. You can try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#show").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
   
    $("#img1").toggle();
    if($("#img1").is(':visible'))
      $("#img2").hide();
    else
      $("#img2").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#img1 {
  display: none;
}

#img2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Photo of Beach </h1>
<h4>Click button below to see a photo of a beach</h4>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <form id="show">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-margin">Show</button>
    <br>

  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="img">

  </div>

  <div class="image1">
    <img src="img/beach-pic.jpg" alt="photo of beach" id="img1">
    <img src="img/lake-pic.jpg" alt="photo of lake" id="img2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, check if #img1 is visible, if yes, then hide #img1 and display #img2, vice versa.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#show").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($("#img1").is(':visible')) {

      $("#img1").hide();
      $("#img2").show();
    } else {

      $("#img1").show();
      $("#img2").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#img1 {
  display: none;
}

#img2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Beach Photo </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Photo of Beach </h1>
  <h4>Click button below to see a photo of a beach</h4>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <form id="show">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-margin">Show</button>
      <br>

    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="img">

    </div>

    <div class="image1">
      <img src="https://kongdeetourthai.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/apple-icon.png" alt="photo of beach" id="img1">
      <img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/google-flat.png" alt="photo of lake" id="img2">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should show one picture on load, the beach... And hide the other.

Then, using a class (you can use class names of your choice!) for both image, you toggle them.

You absolutely do not need a form for that. I removed it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".photo-switcher").click(function(){
    $(".togglingImg").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#img1 {
  display: inline;
  height:200px;
}

#img2 {
  display: none;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Beach Photo </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Photo of Beach </h1>
    <h4>Click button below to see a photo of a beach</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn photo-switcher">Show</button><br>
    <br>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/127673/pexels-photo-127673.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="photo of beach" id="img1" class="togglingImg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Lake_mapourika_NZ.jpeg" alt="photo of lake" id="img2" class="togglingImg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, img1 and img2 are hidden (because css: display none)

first click, toggle for img1 and show() for img2. since img1 is hidden - toggle will show it and img2 shows because of show()

second click toggle and show again. since img1 is showed - toggle will hide it and img2 shows because of show()

Comment: Is there a way to fix it so that only img1 shows on the first click and the img2 shows when the button is clicked for the second time.